# Android transparent property does not work on Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Im trying to make transparent `Buttons` and `editText`s, I'm using a custom xml file, it works on Android 5 as expected (all fields are indeed transparent), but when running the same app on the emulator using Android 4.1.1, these fields appear black.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

How can the transparency effect be achieved on older android OS's?

Comment: try to set alpha value to your button or edittext

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting background as transparent is working api level 4.0 onwards add below line in your xml

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or Try some thing like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a color property to your shape tag:

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the transparent colour yourself, just to be sure it's not a framework thing.

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Transparency definitely works on Jelly Bean, so I suspect it could be the emulator.